# How can I remove the Ubuntu Dock category from the GNOME settings application?

Tags: gnome, system-settings, ubuntu-dock, dock, gnome-control-center

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 and removed Ubuntu dock with this:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

dock has been removed but still have the dock settings in GNOME settings:

[image: Empty Ubuntu Dock settings]

How can I remove that option from settings?

**Why I removed Ubuntu Dock extension**

Ubuntu 18.04.3 removed some Dock settings in dconf (`/org/gnome/shell/extensions/`).
and just because of that I cannot change the dock settings to what I like. I've decided to remove that and use dash to dock extension instead (on 18.04.2, Ubuntu dock had the same dconf settings as Dash to Dock Extension but on 18.04.3 some of those settings are gone and some of those are not changing anything in dock).

If I don't remove Ubuntu Dock and only install dash to dock extension, I could have 2 docks. so the Ubuntu dock should be removed.

[image: Two Dash to Docks]

Comment: $64,000 question... why are you trying to remove the dock and its settings?

Comment: You don't need to remove `Ubuntu Dock` when installing `Dash to Dock`. `Dash to Dock` is a superset of `Ubuntu Dock`. You won't get two docks leaving both installed. `Ubuntu Dock` should normally show as disabled anyway. Also know that `Dash to Dock` has problems in 19.04.

Comment: What version DtD are you running?

Comment: Try v66 available at https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/. I suspect that you have a setting wrong in DtD. You can also try disabling ALL other GNOME extensions to make sure there's not a conflict.

Comment: @heynnema Installed that but it seems v66 not working on GNOME Shell 3.28.4. v66 changelog (dash to dock website): `Introducing support for Gnome Shell 3.32 and dropping support for previous versions.`

Comment: Oh, that wasn't very nice of them :-( Remove v66 AND v65. Open `dconf` and navigate to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions`, right-click on `dash-to-dock` and select `reset recursively`. Then reinstall v65 and see what it looks like.

Comment: @heynnema It didn't fix the problem by doing that. I installed v66 again and then removed `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` and then removed v66. Installed `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` again. Now the Ubuntu dock has the exact look as I configured for `Dash to Dock v65`. It is a strange fix, because `Ubuntu Dock` didn't respond to any of those settings before and now just by removing a broken extension it just respond! The strange thing is that if I install v65 again I will have 2 docks!

Comment: Yes, some of the DtD settings effect the standard `Ubuntu Dock`, as DtD is a superset of `Ubuntu Dock`. Had you tried the `reset recursively` that I mentioned? So right now... you're just running standard `Ubuntu Dock` right now, yes?

Comment: There's also a possibility that some other extension was conflicting with v65. Show me `ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema Yes I did `reset recursively` and Yes I'm using only `Ubuntu Dock` right now. Disabled all extensions before. doesn't seem to be have some conflict in extensions. but this is my ls result:

Comment: `alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com  Move_Clock@rmy.pobox.com
better-osd                                               remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com
bettervolume@tudmotu.com                                 steal-my-focus@kagesenshi.org
dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com                            TopIcons@phocean.net
hide-app-icon@mrapp.sourceforge.com                      user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
icon-hider@kalnitsky.org                                 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com`

Comment: I recognize TopIcons causes problems... but you have enough other extensions... that might take two to interfere with each other... that the old "disable and recheck" might still be instructive.